# Python Program Freezes Without Error After a Few Hours of Running Continuously

Tags: python, windows, speech-recognition, freeze

I'm writing a simple python program to control my LED lights with voice commands and am running into a problem: after a few hours of continuous running, it freezes without any kind of error. I checked task manager every time it was frozen and it didn't show any thing significant, everything was well within normal parameters. I believe it may have something to do with the SpeechRecognition module I'm using, as it always freezes in the "recordAudio()" function below.

(Excuse the iffy code, I'm new to programming)

```
from BLEDevices import *
import speech_recognition as sr
import winsound
import wolframalpha
import pyttsx3

app_id = 'V3R5HG-H7U9VH6YR4'
client = wolframalpha.Client(app_id)
engine = pyttsx3.init()

def recordAudio(phrase):
    # obtain audio from the microphone
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print(phrase)
        audio = r.listen(source)

    # recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
    try:
        data = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("Speech Recognition thinks you said " + data)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        return "failed"
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results from Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))
        return "failed"
    return data
    
def wolfram(text):
    try:
        res = client.query(text)
        result = next(res.results).text
    except:
        result = 'Unable to Answer Query'
    print(result)
    engine.say(result)
    engine.runAndWait()
    
def processAudio(text):
    if ('color' in text or 'light' in text or 'led' in text or 'brightness' in text or 'work mode' in text or 'relax mode' in text):
        led_control(text)
    else:
        wolfram(text)
    

while True:
    text = recordAudio('Listening for "Controller"...').lower()
    if 'controller' in text:
        winsound.Beep(500, 100)
        text = recordAudio('Listening...').lower()
        processAudio(text)
    else:
        print('\b', end='')
```